# is it true that $\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + bi) = 0 \implies \zeta(a + bi) \neq 0$ for $0 < a < 1$, $a\neq \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: riemann-zeta

I was wondering if a zero on the critical line implies no zero for the zeta function anywhere else in the **critical strip** for the same ordinate and vice-versa? I don't know if there is a proof for this.

That is does,

$\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + bi) = 0 \implies \zeta(a + bi) \neq 0$ for $0 < a <\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2} < a < 1$

Thank you

Comment: By $\zeta(a,b),$ you mean $\zeta(a+bi)$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: it is true. I think I have the proof on my notebook, give me a sec and I will look for it brb

Comment: I would be surprised if it is proven. @hellofriends

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact for any negative even integer
$$
\zeta(-2n) = 0\ \forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

Comment: i am interested in $a$ inside the critical strip.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. I'll try with contraposition. Your statement is if $\zeta(\frac12+bi)=0$, then for all $\frac12\ne a\in \Bbb R, \zeta(a+bi)\ne0$. So, its contraposition is if there exists $\frac12\ne a\in \Bbb R$ such that $\zeta(a+bi)=0$, then $\zeta(\frac12+bi)\ne0$.

The Riemann zeta holds this functional equation:
$$
\zeta(x)=2^x\pi^{x-1}\sin\frac{\pi x}2\Gamma(1-x)\zeta(1-x)
$$
Substitute $x$ as $-2n$ $(0<n\in\Bbb Z)$, then the term $\sin\frac{\pi x}2$ goes to $0$, so $\zeta(-2n)=\zeta(-2n+0i)=0$.

But $\zeta(\frac12+0i)=-1.46035\cdots\ne0$, so the contraposition is false.

So your statement goes to false.

Comment: i am interested in $a$ inside the critical strip.

Comment: Then you'ld rather edit the title from $a\ne\frac12$ to $0<a<1, a\ne\frac12$. I'll try to answer about critical strip...